# How to create a custom filter in stack exchange to find all answered questions with Green ticks?

Tags: discussion

I am trying to create a custom filter in stack exchange to find all **answered** questions on a particular topic(that has green tick). I was able to filter by topic name. But how do I further filter on answered questions that has green tick?

I might be chosing wrong tag, because could not find what tag to to choose.

Comment: This question belongs over at Meta Salesforce Stack Exchange, which is for questions about the site. I'll move it over there for you.

Comment: Thanks @DavidReed. Do you have any answer for my question? looks like you are a regular contributor here.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe you can filter for questions that have accepted answers, although it's possible there's a way to do it that I don't know about. (You could surely do it through a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/salesforce/query/new) on Stack Exchange Data Explorer, but I don't think that's what you're aiming for here).

The custom filter UI (accessible by clicking through to a tag, and then clicking Filter) offers options to select questions *without* answers, and without *accepted* answers, but I don't know of any way to generate a filter view that just includes questions that have accepted answers.

[image]